# How can I access AWS AppConfig feature flag in a angular frontend

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-app-config, feature-flags

At our organization we are using AWS AppConfig to manage feature flags throughout our development cycle, AppConfig flags are easily accessible in backend services like lambda etc. but our frontend is single action page build using angular and we are looking into ways to get those feature flags into the frontend any suggestions will be helpful.

Till now i tried using @aws-sdk/client-appconfigdata  but not able to find a way to set the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY into the client side sdk. any help with this will also be helpful.

Comment: Don't add your AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY  on the client side. Store those keys in the environmental variable and used on your client side.